# Phaser: remove a circle previously drawn with drawCircle

Tags: phaser-framework

In Phaser (2.4.x), I'm drawing a circle around a sprite when it is dragged:

```
function dragStart(sprite, pointer, dragX, dragY) {
    var graphics = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
    graphics.lineStyle(6, 0x909090, 0.3);
    graphics.drawCircle(dragX, dragY, 200);
}
```

That works fine, but now I need to remove the circle when the drag ends, and I can't figure that part out:

```
function dragStop() {
    // ?
}
```

Is it possible to remove graphics? Is there a better or simpler option to draw a circle and remove it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [kill()](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.2/Phaser.Graphics.html#kill) the object

But be carefull with the scope of the var you want kill (you are defining it inside the function).

Or you could just create the graphic and then show or hide depending of your event (drag)

I leave you a very simple example with both solutions:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 500, Phaser.AUTO, 'game');
var mainState = { 
create:function(){
    var graphics = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
    graphics.lineStyle(6, 0x909090, 0.3);
    graphics.drawCircle(game.world.centerX+100,game.world.centerY+100, 200);
    console.log(graphics);
    setTimeout(function(){
     graphics.kill();
      },2000);
    this.graphics2 = game.add.graphics(0, 0);
    this.graphics2.lineStyle(6, 0xff0000, 1);
    this.graphics2.drawCircle(game.world.centerX-100,game.world.centerY-100, 200);
    this.graphics2.visible = false;
    this.show_later = game.time.now + 2000;
    this.hide_again = game.time.now + 4000;
    
},

update:function(){
 if(this.show_later < game.time.now){
   this.graphics2.visible = false;
  }
  if(this.hide_again < game.time.now){
   this.graphics2.visible = true;
  }
},
};
game.state.add('main', mainState);  
game.state.start('main');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div id="game"></div>
```